# Firebase together with sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, firebase

I have an app (field data collection) where I used the sign in option and authentication with firebase. 
All the other database the default option is to store data as a local SQLite database, however, I want to add the option if the user wants to sign in and transfer the local database to an online database so it can be accessed on multiple devices.
Can I have together firebase and sqlite? 
I mean can the user store the data offline and when goes online with a sync button can have the data online in the firebase cloud? 
My sqlite database stores data from drop down columns, google maps longtitude and latitude data, voice recordings and images. 
I would appreciate your help, and hope you understand my questions!
Yours sincerely, 
Tzirineto

Comment: You can have many database in app so yes you can. Example me I have SQLite and the personal file storing.

Comment: Seems like a lot of duplicate work. Why not just store everything in Firebase and call it a day?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be possible. The data in SQLite is stored in the form of tables i.e rows and columns i.e. its a relational database. But the data in the firebase id store in the form of documents i.e. key-value pair. Your first step is to create objects in Java. Then it will be easy for you to dump same objects in both SQLite and in firebase. Also you have to maintain a proper relations among the data using uid in firebase. When the user clicks sync button you have to add the objects in the firebase. In order to do that first you have to retrieve the complete data from SQLite and store it into java objects then send them to firebase. You have to keep a check among relationship that exists among the data. Hope it helps

Comment: Did it helped @Tzirineto ?